# Limiting generic types in C#

Tags: c#, generics, types

I have a generic class `MyClass<T>` where `T` should **only** be those types which can be compared.

This would mean only numeric types and classes where methods for the relational operators have been defined. How do I do this ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot constrain to operators, but you can constrain to interfaces. Therefore, intending to use `>=, <=, ==` is out, but you could use `CompareTo, Equals`.

```
where T : IComparable<T>
```

[Interface documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx)

This interface brings you the `CompareTo` method which is useful for relational ordering (greater than, less than, etc.). Primitives and strings implement this already, but you would need to implement this for your own custom types. You would use it like this

```
void SomeMethod<T>(T alpha, T beta) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    if (alpha.CompareTo(beta) > 0) 
    {
        // alpha is greater than beta, replaces alpha > beta
    }
    else if (alpha.CompareTo(beta) < 0)
    {
        // alpha is less than beta, replaces alpha < beta
    }
    else 
    {
        // CompareTo returns 0, alpha equals beta
    }
}
```

`Equals` you get by default as a virtual method on `object`. You want to override this method on your own custom types if you want something other than referential equality to be used. (It is also strongly recommended to override `GetHashCode` at the same time.)

Comment: IComparable doesn't have the Equals method, thats IEquatable

Comment: @nathan, you are correct, but `Equals` is a virtual method on objects by default, so I didn't mention the interface in the answer. Will update for clarity.

Comment: I did so but now I'm getting the error `operator < cannot not be applied to T and T`. Do I have to implement CompareTo() ? I was thinking that the compiler would figure out how this is done based on the type.

Comment: @rohit89, As said, you cannot use those operators. You cannot constrain on them, and the compiler cannot guarantee that they are defined. You want to use the `CompareTo` method, which is already available for int, string, double, etc. You would need to implement the interface on your own classes if they were to also use the generic method/class.

Comment: Ok, I have a problem here. I'm trying to convert a class that worked with `int` to a generic one. There are multiple places where comparisons are done with the relational operators.  How do I deal with those lines ?

Comment: @rohit89, I'll provide a sample.

Answer (score 3):

You can limit the generic type to only classes that implement the IComparable interface using the where modifier.

```
public class MyClass<K> where K : IComparable
{
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to limit it to things that can be compared, you can do things like:

```
public class MyClass<T> where T:IComparable
```

Answer (score -1):

If speed is of relevance using the suggested methods will give you a tremendous loss in performance. If not, all the suggested things work fine.

This is an issue I have to address very often since the primitive datatypes in C# do not have an "Numeric" datatype as often suggested and demanded by others here.

Maybe the next release of C# will have it, but I doubt...

Comment: Why do you think performance degrades? I am not too sure why you mentioned numeric data type here. Which numeric type would you like to have?

Comment: I did a lot of tests recently, because in our framework we need a very flexible type system. Assume you have an generic array of different primitive datatypes. How would you run through an array? How would you perform a comparison of a generic array. How would you do math operations on this array since there are operations defined on a generic a generic datatype. This is one reason to have a numeric datatype restriction. Maybe this is a little too few text to explain my situation, but there are many threads around here that show the problem.